# Upload PHP Code not uploading image

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I am trying out the following code inside a wordpress template:

```
<?php
//connect to database. Username and password need to be changed
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");

//Select database, database_name needs to be changed
mysql_select_db("database_name");

if (!$_POST['uploaded']){
//If nothing has been uploaded display the form
?>

<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
Upload:<br><br>
<input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="uploaded" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?
}else{
//if the form hasn't been submitted then:

//from here onwards, we are copying the file to the directory you made earlier, so it can then be moved 
//into the database. The image is named after the persons IP address until it gets moved into the database

//get users IP
$ip=$REMOTE_ADDR;

//don't continue if an image hasn't been uploaded
if (!empty($image)){

//copy the image to directory

copy($image, "/temporary/".$ip."");

//open the copied image, ready to encode into text to go into the database
$filename1 = "/temporary/".$REMOTE_ADDR;
$fp1 = fopen($filename1, "r");

//record the image contents into a variable
$contents1 = fread($fp1, filesize($filename1));

//close the file
fclose($fp1);

//encode the image into text
$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents1)); 

//insert information into the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (img,data)"."VALUES ('NULL', '$encoded')");

//delete the temporary file we made
unlink($filename1);
}

//end
}
?>
```

I have created a directory called "temporary" in my web root. This file is inside: wp-content/themes/mytheme/ directory.

I have also set the directory permissions to chmod 777.

When I try to upload nothing happens and nothing is uploaded to the directory and nothing is added to the database either.

All that happens after I try to uploads is that the page redirects to the home page.

Comment: There's not mysql db involved in that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this?

```
if (!empty($image)){
```

Your image is in array

```
$_FILES['image']
```

Comment: Don't understand what your solution is...could you explain please?

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx    Hire You can find info about $_FILES and storing it into db